# Making a deep hash from an array of elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array eg. `arr = [:a, :b, :c]` and i would like to make a hash from it in the form of

```
[{:a => [{:b => [:c] } ] } ]
```

Comment: "Making a deep hash" in the title is problematic in two ways. Firstly you're making an array, not a hash, and "nested" is probably more what you're looking for than "deep". Perhaps, "Making an array of nested hashes and arrays from an array."? (All arrays contain elements (:- and "Ruby" is taken care of by the tag.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
[{ arr.shift => [{ arr.shift => [arr.shift] }] }]
```

To Cary's point, this is a little less dirty:

```
[{ arr[0] => [{ arr[1] => [arr[2]] }] }]
```

Or:

```
enum = arr.each
[{ enum.next => [{ enum.next => [enum.next] }] }]
```

If you're looking for something a little more flexible, here's a recursive method that does it:

```
def nest(arr)
  head, *tail = arr
  return [head] if tail.empty?
  [{ head => nest(tail) }]
end

nest([:a, :b, :c]) # => [{:a=>[{:b=>[:c]}]}]
```

Comment: You could also redefine the method signature: `nest(head, *tail)` and call it like `nest(*tail)`.

Comment: Whoa, that first example *is* quick and dirty.  What makes you think that your left-most `arr.shift` always gets evaluated first, followed by the one in the middle, before the one on the right?  If a different Ruby version evaluates things in a different order, your results will change.

Comment: @tadman That's a neat idea, but the starting input is an array, so I wanted it to be compatible with that (i.e. without requiring the caller to splat it).

Comment: @DavidGrayson It's not just the left-most, it's also the outer-most. What makes you think Ruby would ever evaluate data structures and expressions inside-out and backwards?

Comment: Aside from @David's point, isn't your quick and dirty an obtuse version of `[{ arr[0] => [{ arr[1] => [arr[2] }] }]` (which, incidentally, doesn't mutate `arr`)?

Comment: mwp: The code in a Ruby interpreter for evaluating a hash might look something like:  `key = evaluate_key_expr(); value = evaluate_value_expr();  add_to_hash(key, value);`  Some programmer might reorder the first two lines some day (so a hash value gets evaluated before the corresponding key) and it would not break most Ruby programs, but it would break your quick and dirty one.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I'm not going to defend that line of code because it was a throwaway intend to segue the discussion into my recursive solution. But at a higher level, you could argue that almost any snippet of Ruby is at risk from a change in the expected order of operations. In `foo = bar + qux`, `bar` could be a method call that affects the value of `qux`, so I shouldn't write that expression because someday Ruby might evaluate `qux` before `bar`? Whether it's in the spec or not, there's an implicit contract in the order of operations in Ruby: left to right, outside-in. Your argument is silly.

Comment: I think most Rubyists don't write code like that, so there is no implicit contract about what `foo = bar + qux` actually means and you shouldn't rely on its behavior always being the same with regards to ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something close with `inject`:

```
arr.reverse.inject([]) { |memo, item| [{item => memo }] }
# => [{:a=>[{:b=>[{:c=>[]}]}]}]
```

and thanks to the comment by Cary, spot on:

```
arr.reverse.inject([]) { |memo, item| memo.empty? ? [item] : [{item => memo }] }
# => [{:a=>[{:b=>[:c]}]}]
```

Comment: [Close only counts in horseshoes and hand grenades.](http://forum.quoteland.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/99191541/m/594103241)

Comment: `arr.reverse.inject([]) { |memo, item| memo.empty? ? [item] : [{item => memo }] } #=> [{:a=>[{:b=>[:c]}]}]`.

Comment: @Kris, that did not display the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t hesitate to mutate an input:

```
loop.inject([]) do |memo|
  break memo unless e = arr.pop
  [memo.empty? ? e : {e => memo}]
end
```

To not mutate the initial array `arr`, call `dup` on it in advance, or use iterator:

```
iter = arr.reverse.each
loop.inject([]) do |memo|
  break memo unless e = iter.next
  [memo.empty? ? e : {e => memo}]
end
```